# Bootstrap's tooltip not visible due to z-index issue?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

How can CSS be used to show the tooltips in the left menu bar in the below fiddle?  I can't use position: fixed because the tooltips need to be absolutely positioned in some cases.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BF5yW/7/

Code:

```
<div class="side-box-menu">
    <div class="viewport">
        <ul>
            <li> <a class="side-box-menu-control nav-text" data-bind="tooltip: { title: 'text', trigger: 'hover', placement: 'right' }"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is not the z-index but the `overflow: hidden` in the `.side-study-box .viewport` style definition. If you remove the `overflow: hidden` it will work. So the question is why have you needed the overflow hidden here originally?

Comment: ah, I missed that.  Feel free to make this the answer or I can delete the question.  Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this a possiblity or am I missing something?
http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/vcXe6/

The only change I made was make

```
side-study-box .viewport {
......  
overflow:visible;  
....
}
```

Good luck!